# Identifying the evaluation measures for unranked lists (set)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision, evaluation, precision-recall

I have a dataframe as follows:
[image]

1. Column 0 (0,1,2,3...) refers to document_ids
2. 40041,37962,37985... are ids representing objects related to the documents.For example, document_id 2 has related (truth) object 37985 and predicted objects 37985,37983.
3. Truth – actual objects (gold standard)
4. Predicted – objects predicted by my algorithm
5. Overlaps – Objects exist in both Truth and Predicted lists
6. Not detected – Objects exist in the Truth list but not detected by the algorithm.

My question:

- Which evaluation measures I can use given the datasets below? precision will not be possible as i dont have false positives yet. How about accuracy or jaccard similarity? Scikit listed several evaluation measures [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). I am looking for measures to evaluate unranked lists..

Comment: You should group those ids together and count. you can use the count to calculate precision and recall

Comment: each of the rows refer to different queries. can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What does your calculation for each row mean?

Comment: let say row#1 refers to query1 which is supposed to return objects [37962, 38338] 'Truth', and the algorithm has inferred objects [38338, 37962].

Comment: There are several unrelated questions here.  Which type of similarity is appropriate; how to calculate something in pandas; and how to plot certain things.   Please try to restrict questions to a single problem.

Comment: you are right, i will edit the question now..

Comment: As you say in your point 2 `"For example, document_id 2 has related (truth) object 37985 and predicted objects 37985,37983"`, so isnt 37983 in prediction a false positive here?

Comment: Also, start from further down the page you suggested: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#from-binary-to-multiclass-and-multilabel